# React Redux hooks in Gatsby useDispatch "Invalid hook call"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, gatsby

I am trying to use Redux in my Gatsby project. I've used Redux before in the past, but never used Hooks before. I thought perhaps it was an issue with Gatsby, but I've been able to use the useStaticQuery hook (as you can see in builder.js below). I've checked all the versions (see below) and rules.

Here's the error I receive:

[image]

Versions:

yarn list react

```
react@16.12.0
```

yarn list react-redux

```
react-redux@7.1.3
```

yarn list redux

```
redux@4.0.4
```

Here's my builder.js code.

```
import {graphql, useStaticQuery} from 'gatsby'
import React from "react"
import Armor from './armor'

export default () => {

  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query Data {
      allArmor(filter: {type: {eq: "chest"}}) {
        totalCount
        nodes {
          name
          attack
          magic
        }
      }
    }`)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.nodes[0]}</h1>
      <Armor/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's my armor.js code. (This is where the error is thrown)

```
import React from "react"
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export default () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT' })}>Increment</button>
  )
}
```

Gatsby related code for redux:

gatsby-browser.js

```
import wrapWithProvider from './wrap-with-provider'
export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

gatsby-ssr.js

```
import wrapWithProvider from './wrap-with-provider'
export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

wrap-with-provider.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import * as reducers from './src/redux/reducers'

const initialState = {
  setCount: 0,
  setTotal: 0,
}

const combinedReducers = combineReducers({ ...reducers })
export default ({ element }) => {
  const store = createStore(combinedReducers, initialState)
  return <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>
}
```

redux/reducers/index.js

```
const setCount = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case `UPDATE`:
      return action.count

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using redux "just like in the past" won't work out of the box.

You need to [setup redux beforehand with gatsby's SSR rendering](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux), ie setup `gatsby-browswer.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`.

> To use redux in a Gatsby site you'll need to hook in to two of Gatsby's extension points.
>
> Once in `wrapRootElement` which runs during Gatsby's server rendering process, and once in `wrapRootElement` which is part of Gatsby's browser APIs.
>
> Check out `./gatsby-ssr.js` and .`/gatsby-browser.js` to see how this is implemented in this example.

That's because the entry point you used to when booting with CRA is not the same entry point as in Gatsby.

Comment: Okay I didn't mention it, but let me add that to my original question, because I do have that code. Sorry.

Comment: If so, try uploading an example with your setup to a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default

Comment: I've added redux and react-redux to the package.json but when it builds I just get -
./src/components/builder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in '/sandbox/src/components'

https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-xudb3

Comment: I dont see any problems, you didn't config as I mentioned in the answer https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-6h92c

Comment: I spent hours trying to get it to work. I configured it the way you did and everything. It worked in the gatsby sandbox just not locally. Must be something simple I am missing. I ended up just forking the using-redux example and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the wrapper again with a react component as below

```js
const FireBaseApp = () => {
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(/* some code */)
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setLoggedIn(!!user)
    })
  })
  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn }}>
      {element}
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Wrapper = ({ element }) => {
  return <FireBaseApp element={element} />
}

exports.wrapRootElement = Wrapper
```

source : 
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22833#issuecomment-609370401